# Can (intrinsic) locks act in different ways in addition to mutexes?

Tags: concurrency, java, mutual-exclusion

I'm reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*, and I came across the following sentence (section **2.3.1 Intrinsic locks**, pg. 25):

> Every Java object can implicitly act as a lock for purposes of synchronization; these built-in locks are called intrinsic locks or monitor locks.
>
> Intrinsic locks in Java act as *mutexes* (or *mutual exclusion locks*), which means that at most one thread may own the lock.

The last sentence seems to suggest that locks can act as "things", in addition to mutexes. If so, what are some examples of these "things"?